# common TSL v1.2 ciphers but handshake failure is reported

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, tls1.2

The curl command in my Linux box uses OpenSSL 1.0.2u to get a site whose ciphers reported by nmap  are:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE  VERSION
443/tcp open  ssl/http Apache httpd
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2
|     Ciphers (4)
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
|     Compressors (1)
|_      uncompressed
```

The OpenSSL 1.0.2u ciphers similar to those above are (I think):

```
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

but curl cannot connect and reports a handshake error

```
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Hello request (0):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure, errno 0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure, errno 0
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the server doesn't like your client certificate. (It it were mismatched ciphers you wouldn't get the server hello.)

Comment: @RichardHeap+ or rather the **lack of client cert**, since there is no CertVerify after ClientKX. In 1.0 up the Client always sends Certificate _message_ when requested, but it may not contain any cert.